# redirect console output to text window in winform app

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following executing a batch file from cmd.exe. I have the output of the process going to a textbox on my winform. The textbox seems to update only when the process ends. I would like each line to show up as the process runs.

```
{
    // prior lines were Process and ProcessInfo setup code

    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    // see below for output handler
    Process proc = Process.Start(startInfo);
    proc.ErrorDataReceived += proc_DataReceived;
    proc.OutputDataReceived += proc_DataReceived;

    proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
    proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
    proc.WaitForExit();
}

void proc_DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    // output will be in string e.Data
    if (e.Data != null)
        BeginInvoke(new Action(() => textBox1.Text += (Environment.NewLine + e.Data)));            
}
```

`
How do I get each line to show up when it is being created? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you calling `proc.WaitForExit();` from the UI thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `proc.WaitForExit();` is your problem--it's a synchronous call that blocks until the process completes.  That means nothing happens on the UI thread (including everything you've `BeginInvoked`) until the process is finished.